# Split a list into smaller equal-sized lists keeping a "middle value"?

Tags: python, list

I am looking for a way to  split a python list in the following way.

So that if I have an array:

`A = [0,1,2,3,4]`

I would be able to get:

```
B = [0,1]

C = [1,2]

D = [2,3]

E = [3,4]
```

Comment: Do you always want pairs, or also e.g. triplets of values? If triplets, should the overlap be 1 or 2 elements?

Comment: I was looking for overlap of 1 element, in this case 1, 2 and 3

Comment: [`pairwise` itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general solution for sublists of length `n` with overlap of `k`:

```
def chunk(lst, n=2, k=1):
    return [lst[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(lst)-k, n-k)]

>>> A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> chunk(A)
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7]]
>>> chunk(A, 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6], [6, 7]]
>>> chunk(A, 5, 2)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This is way easier than you think. You can use the same algorithm that itertools uses for their pairwise recipe except `itertools.tee` isn't needed as your input is a list therefore slicing will work.

```
B, C, D, E = zip(A, A[1:])
```

Results:

```
>>> print(B, C, D, E, sep='\n')
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension to create a list of these lists:

```
pairs = [A[i : i + 2] for i in range(len(A) - 1)]
```

If you then want to unpack them into different variables, you can use tuple unpacking:

```
B, C, D, E = pairs
```